注音是字嗎? Are Mandarin Phonetic Symbols characters?
最近我與妹妹在爭「注音符號是不是字」。有人有什麼看法嗎?
translation:
recently, I argued with my sister about whether Mandarin phonetic symbols (Zhuyin) are characters. Does anyone have any idea?

「字」翻譯成英語因該是「character」，不是 「letter」。「Letter」是「字母」，所以目前問題的英語版跟中文版不同了; "Yes, Mandarin Phonetic Symbols are letters" (注音符號確實是字母), but 注音符號不是字。

作为一个母语是中文的人，我竟然不知道什么是注音符号，请问你能举个例子吗？例如你说的注音符号是他们(ta men)中的ta men吗？

音標 是 "字" 嗎？  注音符號 就像是音標一樣的東西存在著，無論是 注音 還是 音標, 每一個 "符號" 僅僅只是表示某個特定聲音而已...

@Tom 他们 的 注音符号 是：他(ㄊㄚ) 们(ㄇㄣ˙)  ； 你們口語說的 bpmf <- ㄅㄆㄇㄈ

@James I see, 我们口语说的bpmf不是汉字，as you said 注音符號是不是字,  请注意注音符號中的符號两个字 --- 符号，符号就是符号，不是汉字，所以注音符號是符号，不是汉字，see https://www.jnmsjc.com/zuowen/16752.html

@Tom 如果他們認定音標是字！ 那麼 也應該認為注音符號是字! 否之亦然

@James 是的，我同意你的说法。根据我的认知，注音符號只是符号，不是汉字。

注音符号 的原名叫做注音字母。注音字母的前身是章太炎的纽文和韵文。在民国初年的新文化运动中，章太炎是一个偏于保守的文人，他反对使用拉丁字母标注汉字读音和汉语书写拉丁化。他使用已经废弃的古代汉字表示纽文和韵文，即声母和韵母。从这样的历史来看，注音符号应该算作汉字。
民国时期，有过各种各样的注音字母方案，比如王照的官话合声字母。这些方案一般都有注音和书写文字两种用途。这样的书写文字类似于日文的假名。在新文化运动中，试图废除汉字的努力遭到守旧文人的强烈的抵制。他们把注音字母这个名字改称为注音符号，表示说，这种符号只限于注音，不作为文字的拼写。受到这种守旧的意识形态的限制，现行教材中都主张注音符号不是字母，更不是文字。

雖說注音符號出自甲骨文，但更改過，且差異很大。可參照此文注音符號的古字（1）。

No.
"注音符號" stands for "phonic marking symbols", similar to the "phonic alphabets (拼音字母)" for English. Individually, it has no meaning but to indicate a particular sound for that symbol; combining 2 or more symbols, the result still does not have meaning but suggests how a given word should be pronounced. The trick is, that there could exist many words with different meanings yet they are pronounced exactly the same, for instance, if you type [ㄊㄚˉ] in a Chinese input app, it will bring up these words - 他/她/它/牠/祂/塌/遢... More examples:

注[ㄓㄨˋ] same pron for 住, 助, 駐, 祝, 柱

音[ㄧㄣ] same pron for 因, 殷, 陰, 蔭

符[ㄈㄨˊ] same pron for 福, 服, 浮, 芙

號[ㄏㄠˋ] same pron for 好, 耗, 浩, 皓



Yes, it is character, or symbol, but No it is NOT “字”
In the context of Chinese, “字” is more of a character that carry meanings, which is more leaning to "word", rather than individual letter.
Where "ZhuYin" only present as component of pronunciation representative. It can be understand as a special character, but not “字”.
